# tooltip corner case tune up facing position adjust improperly on mouseover/hover

Tags: javascript, css

HTML, a sample content of HTML code.

CSS, I'm using css for style and trigger hover effect.

JS, the logic part of trigger tooltip effect, and the tool tip jump on 2nd time trigger. First time trigger, the position is wrong, then the 2nd time it adjusts the position cause the tooltip jump.

```js
var eoTrigger = document.querySelector('.trigger');
var eoTooltipContainer = document.querySelector('.tooltipContainer');

eoTrigger.onmouseover = function() {
  if (eoTrigger.childNodes[0] != eoTooltipContainer) {
    eoTrigger.insertBefore(eoTooltipContainer, eoTrigger.childNodes[0]);
  } else {
    console.log('true');
  }

  // corner case for top
  if (eoTooltipContainer.offsetHeight < eoTrigger.offsetTop) {
    eoTooltipContainer.style.top = eoTrigger.offsetTop - eoTooltipContainer.offsetHeight + 'px';
  } else {
    eoTooltipContainer.style.top = eoTrigger.offsetTop + 18 + 'px';
  }

  // corner case for right
  if (eoTooltipContainer.offsetWidth > window.innerWidth - eoTrigger.offsetLeft) {

    eoTooltipContainer.style.left = (eoTrigger.offsetLeft + eoTrigger.offsetWidth - eoTooltipContainer.offsetWidth) + 'px';

  } else {
    eoTooltipContainer.style.left = eoTrigger.offsetLeft + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
.tooltipContainer {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.trigger:hover .tooltipContainer {
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.trigger {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting</div>
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, <span class="trigger">Lorem Ipsum</span> remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

<span class="tooltipContainer">
      <div class="tooltip">
        remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
      <div class="tooltip">
        Node 2
      </div>
      <div class="tooltip">
        Node 3
      </div>
    </span>
```

But it is not quite stable. Any hint?

You need make sure the trigger word is close to the right (trigger.right < tooltip.width).

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in Safari OS X. What browser are you using?

Comment: I was using chrome, let me try safari.